# How to update SQL column based on previous search result of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a table with columns:

1. ID
2. Comment
3. Date
4. Previous_Comment
5. Previous_Date

Everyday, new records get added to it in bulk. I am supposed to write an update command which will run AFTER the bulk insert.

User has capability to enter **ID** and **Comment**, the column **Date**, **Previous_Comment** and **Previous_Date** get automatically filled.

Date gets filled with todays date.

**Previous_Comment** should have the last comment with the same **ID** but the latest date. So if **ID** is 2, it will find the comment of a previous row with **ID = 2** and the most recent date, fetch the comment from that row and populate the **previous_comment** of the current row (similarly for **previous_date**.)

The problem is that, if we update an entire column, the query gets executed for every row, row-wise. Hence for each row i want this to be executed.
Ps. Since I only want the rows which have been added today, to be affected, i am putting a condition for date to be today's date using **getdate()**.

I have a feeling this is wrong:

```
update table xyz
set previous_date=max(select date from xyz where ID=ID)
where date=getdate();
```

the first ID in the query(ID=ID) is for querying and second refers to ID of the current row which is executing it.

I know this is wrong. please help :(

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a function called `getdate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table xyz x1
  join (select ID,
               max(date) as m_date
        from xyz x2
        where date<:date
        group by ID) x2 on x1.ID=x2.ID
set previous_date=x2.m_date
where date=:date;
```

Like this?

Comment: what do you mean by :date ?? @StanislavL